# Interpreting multiple modules

Tags: chicken-scheme

I would like to have multiple modules in my program.  Eg. module `foo`, and module `bar`.  Module `foo` would refer to module `bar`. Then I would like to be able to test those modules in the csi (interpreted) repl.  The root of this question is if I can run my code withouth having to compile it.  Below is my example.

Note:  I'm a scheme newbie, so there may be other issues with this code.  Feel free to point anything out, and I will try to correct.

**foo.scm**

```
(use r7rs)
(define-library (foo)
  (import (scheme base)
          (prefix bar bar:))
  (export add-some-stuff)
  (begin

    (define baz 1)

    (define (add-some-stuff)
      (+ baz bar:bork))

    ))
```

**bar.scm**

```
(use r7rs)
(define-library (bar)
  (import (scheme base))
  (export bork)
  (begin

    (define bork 2)))
```

Results would hope to be:

```
$ csi
> ,l foo.scm
> (import (prefix foo foo:))
> (foo:add-some-stuff)
;;=> 3
```

Here's the error I get:

```
$ csi -q
#;1> ,l foo.scm
; loading foo.scm ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/r7rs.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/chicken.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/numbers.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/foreign.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/srfi-4.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/scheme.base.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/r7rs-support.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/extras.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/srfi-13.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/r7rs-compile-time.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/r7rs-library.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/r7rs-support.so ...

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: syntax-rules

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: cond-expand

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: define-record-type

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: include

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: include

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: import

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: import-for-syntax

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: cond-expand

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: import-for-syntax

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: import
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/r7rs.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/numbers.so ...
; loading /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/4.12.0/lib/chicken/8/scheme.base.so ...

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: syntax-rules

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: import-for-syntax

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: import

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: cond-expand

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: import-for-syntax

Note: re-importing already imported syntax: import

Error: (import) during expansion of (import ...) - cannot import from undefined module: bar

    Call history:

    numbers.scm:1672: scan-real
    <syntax>      (define-library (foo) (import (scheme base) (prefix bar bar:)) (export add-some-stuff) (begin (defin...
    <syntax>      (##core#module foo ((##r7rs#foo)) (##core#define-syntax ##r7rs#foo (##core#lambda _ (quote (##core#u...
    <syntax>      (##core#define-syntax ##r7rs#foo (##core#lambda _ (quote (##core#undefined))))
    <syntax>      (##core#lambda _ (quote (##core#undefined)))
    <syntax>      (##core#begin (##core#quote (##core#undefined)))
    <syntax>      (##core#quote (##core#undefined))
    <syntax>      (##core#undefined)
    <syntax>      (##sys#provide (##core#quote foo))
    <syntax>      (##core#quote foo)
    <syntax>      (import-for-syntax (only r7rs begin cond-expand export import import-for-syntax include include-ci s...
    <syntax>      (##core#undefined)
    <syntax>      (import (only r7rs begin cond-expand export import import-for-syntax include include-ci syntax-rules...
    <syntax>      (##core#undefined)
    <syntax>      (##core#begin (import (scheme base) (prefix bar bar:)) (##core#begin (export add-some-stuff) (##core...
    <syntax>      (import (scheme base) (prefix bar bar:))  <--
#;1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kooda from the #chicken irc channel recommended the [system egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/system), and it seems to be doing what I'm looking for.  In short, one needs to create a `.system` file that specifies the dependency tree, which is described below.  It's a little unfortunate that Chicken Scheme can't figure out the internal module dependencies from looking at the import statements in each module, but I think this is the next best thing.

```
$ chicken-install system
```

create a file called `so-question-chicken-scheme.system`.  That file should contain:

```
(define-system so-question-chicken-scheme
  (scheme-file "bar")
  (scheme-file "foo" depends: '("bar")))
```

Here's the interpreter results

```
$ csi -q
#;1> (use system)
#;2> (load "so-question-chicken-scheme.system")
#;3> (load-system so-question-chicken-scheme)
#;4> (import (prefix foo foo:))
#;5> foo:add-some-stuff
#<procedure (add-some-stuff)>
#;6> (foo:add-some-stuff)
3
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a few issues with this:

1. The syntax for loading the `bar` module is wrong, `import` expects a list of libraries, where `(scheme base)` would be one and `(prefix bar bar:)` would be another.
2. While the R7RS egg adds support for its module syntax, it reuses the existing module loading support which relies on having compiled modules to a shared library and an import library in a loadable location, like the egg repository or the current directory.  You'll therefore have to compile both modules in the right order with `csc -R r7rs -sJ` before using them.
3. `csc -R r7rs -sJ bar.scm` succeeds, `csc -R r7rs -sJ foo.scm` doesn't.  This is because the former invocation emits `other-module.import.scm` due to `(define-library (other-module) ...)`.  This needs to be changed to match the identifier you import it as.

With these changes I can reproduce your example session successfully.  Here's a summary of the build steps and input files:

```
csc -R r7rs -sJ bar.scm
csc -R r7rs -sJ foo.scm
```

**foo.scm**

```
(use r7rs)
(define-library (foo)
  (import (scheme base)
          (prefix bar bar:))
  (export add-some-stuff)
  (begin

    (define baz 1)

    (define (add-some-stuff)
      (+ baz bar:bork))

    ))
```

**bar.scm**

```
(use r7rs)
(define-library (bar)
(import (scheme base))
(export bork)
(begin

    (define bork 2)))
```

Comment: thanks for your thorough answer!  The root of my question is really about whether I can use the interpreter on the code in my project without having to compile.  Which it appears that I cannot, but maybe that's not yet definitive.  I fixed the other errors in my example.